# Phonegap VideoPlayer Plugin Sample Code

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins, input

I'm trying to implement a VideoPlayer on my Phonegap Application.
I have the idea to implement this plugin :

https://github.com/dawsonloudon/VideoPlayer

It should be simple but i'm really beginning with HTML/Javascript interaction.
I just need a sample code that would allow me to link an :
 
- Input File Type HTML Tag
 
- This plugin

Best regards

Comment: You should not ask for code on StackOverflow, but you should try to do it yourselve and when you get stuck, ask a question with the code you have tried and the problem description. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask